# Create a monorepo with ionic and react (and capacitor)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, monorepo

I understood that Ionic cannot handle 'yarn workspace' which build the project with `react-app-rewired` https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4430

As suggested in this post, I configure my monorepo with the multi-app option( https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#multi-app-projects)

To valide the project structure, I firstly tried to share a simple constants.

```
import * as ROLES from '../../../../lib/constants'
```

but when I launch `ionic serve --project=app`

Have got this error :

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../lib/constants
> which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports
> outside of src/ are not supported.

Project structure :

[image]

ionic.config.json

```
{
  "defaultProject": "myProject",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "name": "My First Ionic App",
      "type": "react",
      "root": "packages/app",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
    }
  }
}
```

How to manage to share files and components ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after several day. I have an answer to build monorepo with Ionic & Capacitor !

1 - Build your monorepo with Yarn workspace
this tutorial is simple and clear : https://jibin.tech/monorepo-with-create-react-app/
Then you will use `react-app-rewired` and not 'react-scripts` anymore

2 - Then do not use `ionic serve` that use `react-scripts`

```
react-app-rewired start
```

3 - and Capacitor !
The command `ionic cap run` also use `react-scripts` then you have to find an alternative

The answer is here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/live-reload : Do not use the Ionic CLI

> Capacitor supports CLIs with live reload capability.
>
> Within capacitor.config.json, create a server entry then configure the url field
> using the local web server’s IP address and port:
>
> "server": {   "url": "http://192.168.1.68:8100",   "cleartext": true
> },

Bonus : I created a script to automatically update capacitor.config.json
https://gist.github.com/damienromito/e6b3930ffde4c7240f109d1de69febb5

Comment: you can also add to package.json 
{ "ionic:serve": "react-app-rewired start"} or 
{ "ionic:build": "react-app-rewired build"} so you can use all the other commands and ionic will use react-app-rewired instead of react-scripts